# Make AgendaList scroll to today by default

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-calendars

I have integrated `AgendaList` in my app and It works quite nicely, I can make the `ExpandableCalendar` select today by default using the `date={getCurrentDate()}` prop but I'm not able to do the same for `AgendaList` as there is no comparable prop, it is worth mentioning that `Agenda` for example has a `selected` prop that does what I'm looking for.

Any idea how to achieve this for `AgendaList`?

https://wix.github.io/react-native-calendars/docs/Components/ExpandableCalendar

Thank you

I tried sorting the data differently to bring today to the top, but this left me with a disorganized agenda list that does not make sense.

Comment: I came to the understanding that if a day is not yet loaded then it cannot be scrolled to, and days' events seem to be loaded in patches for performance reasons presumably, so maybe if it is possible to force load all days it will scroll to today's date...